# mssql update trigger needs to do two compares for a single predicate

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I am writing an update trigger for a sql2008r2 database application that can issue either one of the following update statements:

```
update Credit 
  SET preferred ='N' 
  WHERE property ='0062' 
     AND account ='279828' 
     AND ( cc <> 'evqYLNO.5ip5' )
```

or

```
update Credit 
  SET preferred ='N' 
  WHERE property ='0062' 
    AND account ='279828' 
    AND ( cc <> '6552508244650009' )
```

The cc field is encrypted in the first instance and unencrypted in the second instance.

Is there a way to assign the where predicate to a variable inside the trigger logic so that I can do two compares for the single predicate?

Comment: If you are asking whether an update trigger can inspect the triggering statement, the answer is no.

Comment: That is what I'm asking.  Thanks.

Comment: A questionable idea is to use [`Context_Info`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180125.aspx) to pass data to a trigger, e.g. the value and an encryption flag. Just search for `CONTEXT_INFO` and `TRIGGER`. _(Did I think that or say that?)_

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly... This is what you are looking for:

```
 WHERE property ='0062' 
 AND account ='279828' 
 AND cc NOT IN ('evqYLNO.5ip5', '6552508244650009')
```

Comment: Unless I can assign the value of the where clause to a variable, I can't build that logic into the trigger.  I need to build a replacement update statement and I can't build the where clause unless I can assign the value being specified to a variable.

Comment: `update Credit 
  SET preferred ='N' 
  WHERE property ='0062' 
    AND account ='279828' 
    AND ( cc <> '6552508244650009' ) `

needs to be replaced with

`Update Credit
 Set preferred = 'N' 
 WHERE poperty = '0062'
 AND account = '279828;
 AND (cc1 <> @cc or cc2 <> @cc)`

where `@cc` is the value specified in the update statement that causes the trigger to fire.

I can't see how to assign the value to `@cc` based on what is being specified in the original query.